# Log with timing of system events (e,g, Flight Mode on/off)

Tags: logging, airplane-mode

I would like to find out at what time my phone (running Android 8.0.0) was last switched into/out of Flight (Airplane) Mode. Ideally, this would be part of a longer log with the timestamps of the last *N* FlightMode events, alongside other system-related events.

I didn't find any quick solutions by searching this site and others. Is there an easy way to find out this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) for this. Run this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts
```

The output would be overwhelming, but you need to look for the string *android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE* there. You can use grep or save the output into a file and then do the search.

Look for that string under Historical Broadcast Background. You would find the timestamp you're looking for. It could look like this:

```
Historical Broadcast background #345:
    BroadcastRecord{48eb128 u-1 android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE} to user -1
    Intent { act=android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE flg=0x10 (has extras) }
      extras: Bundle[{state=true}]
    caller=android 1298:system/1000 pid=1298 uid=1000
    enqueueClockTime=2019-01-10 00:00:01 dispatchClockTime=2019-01-10 00:00:01
```

You can also look under Historical Broadcasts summary (background).

```
#15: act=android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE flg=0x10 (has extras)
    0 dispatch +1ms finish
    enq=2019-01-10 00:19:14 disp=2019-01-10 00:19:14 fin=2019-01-10 00:19:14
    extras: Bundle[{state=false}]
```

`state=true` means Airplane mode was activated. `state=false` means it was deactivated.

All of this may seem like a trouble, so I suggest you use an automation app to listen to the intent for Airplane mode and take an action for you for convenience.

Both Tasker and [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) should be able to help with this. In MacroDroid,

**Trigger**: Intent Received First:

- Action: android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE

  - Intent Extra:

    - Extra name: state
    - Extra value to match: true

**Actions**: do what you want with that

**Constraints**: none

Save this. Now clone this, configure the trigger and change the value for state to false. So you would have triggers for both states of Airplane mode.

Comment: Super answer, thank you! This would be the only way to do it I guess, i.e. there's no "app for it"? :)

Comment: I would have saved myself the trouble if I knew such an app. :D